# Create a list of grouped element in a column (pandas)

Tags: python, list, pandas

Data:

```
id_num  House Color
6589    Smith yellow
6589    Cordero pink 
6589    Martinez brown
6589    Rossi  black
8956    Portella green
8956    Fusco  purple
8956    Benito white
1064    Dimingo  red
1064    Martinez indigo
1064    Schultz  violet
```

I need to create a list by grouping the id_num in this way with pandas

id_list = (6589,8956,1064)

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: depends on how you want to aggregate or group.  if you wanted tabs of "House Color" by "id_num", for example, you'd do something like `df.groupby('id_num').value_counts()`.  Just depends on exactly what you are trying to do here (which is not clear)

Comment: Thanks so much Nihal. I simply need to find a way to write a list as id_list = (6589,8956,1064) in my main code without the need to write it manually. In the example I have only three number, but I might have 100, 500...so on. In that case I need a script line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) or [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and convert to `tuple`:

```
a = tuple(df.id_num.unique())
```

---

```
a = tuple(df.id_num.drop_duplicates())

print (a)
(6589, 8956, 1064)

print (type(a))
<class 'tuple'>
```

If want `list`:

```
b = df.id_num.unique().tolist()
```

---

```
b = df.id_num.drop_duplicates().tolist()
print (b)
[6589, 8956, 1064]

print (type(b))
<class 'list'>
```